# one .toggle works, the other doesn't and they are identical aside from id's/classes?

Tags: jquery

I have two .toggle events based on different .on('click') conditions. One works and the other doesn't and I have no clue what would be causing it? I have other similar on click functions taking place throughout my web app and they all work aside from this one.

```
//
// WORKS
// 
$('#roster01, #roster02, #roster03').on('click', '.hero', function (e) {
    $(this).find('.hero-select').toggle();
});

//
// DOESN'T WORK ?
// 
$('#roster01, #roster02, #roster03').on('click', '.trinket', function (e) {
    $(this).find('.trinket-select').toggle();
    console.log('test');
});
```

Just to clarify, my HTML class is indeed .trinket and .trinket-select. What's weird, is if I were to comment out the working function and change .trinket-select with .hero-select in the doesn't work function, it won't toggle hero-select either BUT, the console logs correctly. Also, I have both class and ID named the same for other reasons not part of this example.

Here is the HTML structure, just so you can see.

```
<div id="roster01">
    <div class="hero">
        <div class="hero-select" id="hero-select"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="trinket">
        <div class="trinket-select" id="trinket-select"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="roster02">
    <div class="hero">
        <div class="hero-select" id="hero-select"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="trinket">
        <div class="trinket-select" id="trinket-select"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="roster03">
    <div class="hero">
        <div class="hero-select" id="hero-select"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="trinket">
        <div class="trinket-select" id="trinket-select"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="roster04">
    <div class="hero">
        <div class="hero-select" id="hero-select"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="trinket">
        <div class="trinket-select" id="trinket-select"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: html structure is not complete to show how js works, instead of selecting multiple id just common class on them and use class. it will be looking much cleaner

Comment: Ohh true, I see now.. hold on.

Comment: Be aware that if you're not careful about when you bind your click event, then the handler could fire multiple times due to multiple event hooks being added, then you'll end up with the console log still happening but consecutive toggles undo-ing the previous toggle.

Comment: edited HTML, I hadn't included everything needed. That represents what it looks like now.

Comment: @Reddog, what do you mean specifically?

Comment: `id` values should be unique within the document.

Comment: It seems to work [here](https://jsfiddle.net/0m94kpqp/). And as Larry already pointed out, your `id` attributes should be unique within your document.